# Mqtt - Use QoS 1 when …

Tags: node.js, mqtt

I'm following the very good tutorial
www.hivemq.com/mqtt-essentials-part-6-mqtt-quality-of-service-levels/
but I can't figure out to implement

> Of course your application must be tolerating duplicates and process
>   them accordingly.

Can to give me a simple example, please ?

for instance now I've like
(I set up my deploy following https://medium.com/@lelylan/how-to-build-an-high-availability-mqtt-cluster-for-the-internet-of-things-8011a06bd000)

```
module.exports.authorizePublish = function(client, topic, payload, callback) {
    var chunks = topic.split('/');
    if(chunks.length === 4) {
        Debug('AUTHORIZING SUBSCRIBE', client.device_id == chunks[1]);
        Debug('NICKNAME', chunks[1]);
        Debug('CHANNEL', chunks[3]);
        Debug('TOPIC', chunks[2]);
        Debug('PAYLOAD', payload.toString('utf8'));

        var data = {
            deviceNickname:chunks[1],
            channel:chunks[3],
            topic:chunks[2],
            payload:payload.toString('utf8')
        };
        Message.insert(data, function (err, message) {
                if (err){
                    Debug(err);
                    return;
                }
                Debug(message);
        });
    }
    callback(null, client.device_id === chunks[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still rather a learner of MQTT than an expert, but my understanding of handling of duplicate messages with QoS 1 is following:

Suppose you have an application that for whatever reason needs to count messages received from a broker. However, you don't want to take duplicate messages (sent when your client didn't ACK the message in time) to be taken into account.

I use Java Paho client, so the code for it would be:

```
int counter = 0;
public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws MqttException {
   if (message.isDuplicate() == false) {
      counter++;
   }
}
```